# Which is better when sending Javascript array to PHP script with jQuery: Using JSON or just let jQuery convert it to query string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery's `$.ajax` function with POST method to send a javascript array to a PHP script (AFAIK, GET method would be analogue):

```js
fruits = [
    {
        color: "yellow",
        taste: "sour"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        taste: "semi-sweet"
    },
]

$.ajax({

    url: "php/script.php",

    data: {
        fruits: fruits
    },

    type: "POST",
});
```

After making the request, the `$_POST` variable in PHP is populated with:

```php
$_POST['fruits'][0]['color']
$_POST['fruits'][0]['taste']
$_POST['fruits'][1]['color']
$_POST['fruits'][1]['taste']
```

Alternatively, in `$.ajax` function call, I could send data as stringified JSON:

```js
    data: {
        fruits: JSON.stringify(fruits);
    },
```

In this scenario, the data would be sent as a single string (performance gain?), but I would have to use `json_decode()` function in PHP, on `$_POST['fruits']` argument:

```
$fruits = json_decode($_POST['fruits']);
```

After using it, I would be able to access the data in a similar way:

```php
fruits[0]['color']
fruits[0]['taste']
fruits[1]['color']
fruits[1]['taste']
```

I wonder, if these methods are similarly good or one of them is better and why. Thank You in advance for sharing Your knowledge :)

Comment: JSON is better because it's lighter for client side ;-)

Comment: @Sundar Bons: While I also feel a strong affection towards JSON, I would really like to rationalize my feeling by some academic arguments ;)

Comment: You're not actually sending an *only* json-encoded string to the server. You're still using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which makes the whole question a bit obsolete. Meaning jQuery **and** php have to serialize/deserialize the input/output. If you really want to compare both methods, you would need to send a *pure* json string as the post-body, and not use `$_POST` on the server side.

Comment: IMO json is a better solution for scalability of your application.

Comment: @Yoshi good point. it will be a good experiment to benchmark these serialization methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is a very fluid concept. you have to consider several factors and I will try to list some of them.

#### Readability:

Json format is highly readable and may map nicely to backend models
which may help you keep a better mental model.

on the other hand query string is not a far behind readability wise but *looks* less like an object.

#### Performance:

Query string content length is 127 bytes

Json content length is 138 bytes

that eleven bytes difference which may be critical on huge systems.

#### Intuition

Your data exchange seems fitting to json.
You send an array of objects and although it is easy to post like you showed I think it is slightly easier to debug and construct.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is more an enterprise/rest (api) way to go. However it's more modern, clean and dynamic it might be overkill for you.

If you're doing a simple post with 2 or 3 strings go right ahead.
One thing to note, posting null values is only really possible with JSON if you want this, hence the more diverse, also as stated nested data is easier with json. But simple contact forms shouldn't bother with this unless you're using Angular or something.

Answer (score 0):

It's most common on POST to use JSON.

Few reasons why:

- querystrings needed to be urlencoded
- it's rather difficult to have complex data(ex. nested objects or nested arrays even) on querystrings
- JSON is native objects on client

Comment: QueryStrings are only part of the url when you're doing a get request

Comment: second_dot: Is it just an intuition or is there some proof?

thrid_dot: And what are the effects of this fact?